# Google Sign In SDK different configuration files for each target

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, google-signin

I'm working on an app that has two targets for a lite and a pro version.

We are using Google's Sign In SDK for the authentication which requires a configuration file called "GoogleService-Info.plist".

**PROBLEM:**

Is there a way to have two different files with the same name and different targets, so each version uses the configuration file required?

Or there is a way to change the configuration file that the SDK uses? I haven't found a way to do this on Google's documentation.

Comment: You could try [this original SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33336418/1040347)

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? Same issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach to achieve this, is to create a separate directory in your project folder for each file. After that, you will be able to add both references and assign them to each target with no issues.

[image: Example]

---

Source: BraveS - [Copy file to root of XCode project when building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118889/copy-file-to-root-of-xcode-project-when-building/33336418#33336418)